# Mui Autocomplete says onChange value can be string

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm rendering a MUI Autocomplete with my custom type like this:

```
type Option = { label: string; value: string };
return (
  <MuiAutocomplete<Option, true, any, true>
    freeSolo={true}
    onChange   // says value can be type Option | string
  />
);
```

However, the `onChange` signature is saying the type of the value can be `Option | string` instead of just `Option`.

See here: https://codesandbox.io/s/freesolo-demo-material-ui-forked-sn8l5i?file=/demo.tsx

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: What says "value can be Option | string"? Where do you see this? In your codesandbox, the error is much more than you say here. Please post the entire error message. Summarizing loses important details that we need to answer your question.

Comment: My apologies. I should have waited for the clarification from my earlier comment before posting an answer. The more I look at this the more confused I am. I see now that when you say "value", you mean "the parameter to `onChange` named `value`" rather than "the value of `onChange`" as I first read it. However, the error message says that `value`'s type is `(Option | string)[]` which isn't the same. Again, please post the actual error message instead of summarizing.

Comment: The part that I'm confused about is that the [MUI documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/) says that `value` has type `T | Array<T>`. I haven't found where the doc specifies where `T` comes from. I currently assume that it is `Option` given by `MuiAutocomplete<Option, true, any, true>`. But that doesn't match up with the type stated in the error message.

Comment: Oh...I think I'm looking at the wrong documentation. The link I just gave is just called `Autocomplete` whereas you are using `MuiAutocomplete`. IDK what the difference is.

Answer (score 0):

You havent defined an onChange function

```
type Option = { label: string; value: string };
const handleOnChange = (e) => {
  console.log('Changed')
}
return (
  <MuiAutocomplete<Option, true, any, true>
    freeSolo={true}
    onChange={handleOnChange}   // says value can be type Option | string
  />
);
```

Comment: I know. Hover over the onChange to see the message I’m talking about.

Comment: @MarksCode You should add the message directly to your question here.

Answer (score 0):

The entire error message in your codesandbox is:

> (JSX attribute) UseAutocompleteProps<Option, true, any, true>.onChange?: (event: React.SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>, value: (string | Option)[], reason: AutocompleteChangeReason, details?: AutocompleteChangeDetails<...>) => void
> Callback fired when the value changes.
>
> @param event — The event source of the callback.
>
> @param value — The new value of the component.
>
> @param reason — One of "createOption", "selectOption", "removeOption", "blur" or "clear".
>
> @param details
>
> Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type '(event: SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>, value: (string | Option)[], reason: AutocompleteChangeReason, details?: AutocompleteChangeDetails<...>) => void'.ts(2322)
> useAutocomplete.d.ts(267, 3): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & AutocompleteProps<Option, true, any, true, "div">'

This says the type must be

```
(event: SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>, value: (string | Option)[], reason: AutocompleteChangeReason, details?: AutocompleteChangeDetails<...>) => void
```

That's not even close to the same as `Option | string`. Rather, it says that `onChange` must be a function which takes 3 required arguments and one optional argument and returns `void`. In fact, in general, any prop that starts with "on" is a callback and must be a function.

One key here is to make sure you understand the entire error message. And when you ask a question, copy/paste the error message instead of typing your own summary. It is easy to miss important details if you don't post the whole thing.

Comment: I said this in the question. The “value” type is Option or string. Not the whole type of the function, just the “value” parameter within it.

Comment: @MarksCode I see now. It will help if you edit your question to make it more clear. When I read "says value can be type...", I read this as "the value of the `onChange` prop can be type...". There is nothing in your question that makes it clear you are talking about a parameter named `value`. Again, it will help if you show the exact text  of the message you are talking about to give more context.

Comment: @MarksCode The answer to your question is because the authors of mui said so. [The documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/) clearly gives the signature for `onClose`. Why they chose to allow `value` to be `string | Option` is a design decision, the reasons for which may or may not be publicly available.

Comment: @MarksCode And the more I look at this, the more confused I get. The error message from your code sandbox says `value` is type `(string | Option)[]`, but the docs I link earlier says `T | Aarray<T>` which look like two different things to me.